# PhoneGap Do Not Backup attribute via setMetadata for sqlLite database?

Tags: ios, cordova, icloud

We had an app rejected for backing too much data to iCloud.  Our app is written using PhoneGap; I've upgraded to 1.8.1 to use the setMetaData function but I can't figure out how to use the File API to access the sqlLite database file to set it to not back up (it's data that would be nice to have for offline use but not user created).

I can get the database created and get to the file system, but I can't figure out where to go from there to get a FileEntry object I can call setMetadata on.

```
 var shortName = 'myDB'; 
 var version = '1.0'; 
 var displayName = 'myDB'; 
 var maxSize = 265536; 
 theDB = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!